# Why does cucumber skin kill ants?

Tags: biochemistry, zoology, entomology

I recently read that cucumber skin is an effective repellent for some ants:

> Set out cucumber peels or slices in the kitchen or at the ants' point of entry. Many ants have a natural aversion to cucumber. Bitter cucumbers work best.
>
> Source: [Natural Insect Pest Control](http://eartheasy.com/live_natpest_control.htm)

See also: [How to Use Cucumbers to Prevent Ants from Entering the Home](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Cucumbers-to-Prevent-Ants-from-Entering-the-Home)

But when I tried it out they died instead. What made this happen?

Comment: Please include the source of your information. Where did you read this?

Comment: There you go @OneFace

Comment: It's always good to include the source, especially when asking about things that are not commonly known.

Comment: Under what circumstance did the ants die? If possible, post a photo of the dead ants near the cucumber skin.

Comment: @MarchHo Sorry , cant post a photo since this was done a few days back .

Comment: Was an edit necessary ?

Comment: I think the ants aren't killed but they are forced to move out because the Cucumber slices are just disabling the ants pheromone tracking system there by forcing them to withdraw from the location.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Cucumber contains a compound called **trans-2-nonenal** ([reference 1](http://www.ghorganics.com/page11.html) and [reference 2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0005276076901612)) that repels insects. This particular compound ([reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Nonenal)) has can also be used in insecticide foams for repelling ants ([reference](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100140368))